# Checkbox must checked for activeflag for Y?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, checkbox, c#-3.0

CheckBox checks the Flag if it is 1 else it unchecks the checkbox when it is 0 in my c# code

```
this.chk_CorpFlag = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();

if (dtGridNwBrandModel.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[10].Value.ToString().ToLower() == "false")
  {
     chk_CorpFlag.Checked = false;
  }
   else
  {
     chk_CorpFlag.Checked = true;
  }
```

How can i automatically checks the checkbox if the values is Y and unchecks when it is N.

Note:cells[10] consists of values Y's or N's.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare it with `Y`, it only two values Y / N you can put uncheck in else part. Also use trim method to avoid space if you expect any.

```
if (dtGridNwBrandModel.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[10].Value.ToString().ToLower().Trim() == "y")
{
     chk_CorpFlag.Checked = true;
}
else
{
     chk_CorpFlag.Checked = false;
}
```

If you expect more then two values in the field you can put condition in else part as well.

```
if (dtGridNwBrandModel.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[10].Value.ToString().ToLower().Trim() == "y")
{
     chk_CorpFlag.Checked = true;
}
else if (dtGridNwBrandModel.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[10].Value.ToString().ToLower().Trim() == "n")
{
     chk_CorpFlag.Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: :I am using your code but its not checking automatically if it is Y .

Comment: What line you are getting the error could you paste that in your comments?

Comment: It working awesome .Just removed ToLower .Thanks Adil

Comment: You are welcome, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work, You would have "Y" and "N" in upper case in condition that is why you need to remove ToLower() call, changing "Y" to "y" and "N" to "n" will work with ToLower() too,